# Limitations of the Self-Incompatibility Mechanism in Plants

Tags: botany, sexual-reproduction, pollination

For a given plant species, how many types of S-loci exists to prevent self-pollination? I would like to know how often a plant stops fertilization process by other plants, thinking the pollens belong to itself due to limitations of SSI/GSI.

Comment: The answer is going to vary dramatically depending on the species.
Have you checked [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-incompatibility)?

Comment: An examples suffices.

Comment: I think you mean to ask how many self-incompatibility alleles generally segregate in natural populations? (@tyersome gives a reasonable answer). I cannot tell if you instead mean how many different S-locus systems (mechanisms) exist. I am happy to provide an alternative answer if you clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Herrera, Sara et al. 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6274852/) suggest that there are at least 33 S-alleles in apricot.

I believe some species of *Brassica* have at least 60 S-alleles identified.

However, there are dominance relationships among these alleles, so I don't think you can directly extrapolate from the number alleles to to the rate at which non-self pollen will be excluded.  The frequencies of the different alleles within a population will clearly also affect this calculation.

In addition, different individuals with the same S-alleles are more likely to be closely related, so I would hesitate to classify this as a limitation of the system.

Ref: Herrera, Sara et al. “Identification of Self-Incompatibility Alleles by Specific PCR Analysis and S-RNase Sequencing in Apricot.” International journal of molecular sciences vol. 19,11 3612. 15 Nov. 2018, doi:10.3390/ijms19113612